# How to interpret this statement?

Tags: probability-theory

> A random variable $X$ is said to be continuous if $P(X = x) = 0$ for all single points $x ∈ X$.

Source： https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.04862.pdf#page=16

1) Why should $P(X=x)$ be 0 for all single points to make the random variable $X$ continuous? What does it mean for $P(X=x)$ to be 0?

2) Can it be true that:

A random variable $X$ is said to be continuous if **and only if** $P(X = x) = 0$ for all single points $x ∈ X$.

It seems obvious that if $P(X = x) = 0$ for all single points $x ∈ X$ a random varible $X$ would be said to be continuous.

3) And if for some points the probabilities are not 0, could that variable be possibly continuous too?

Comment: What about this statement is unclear to you?

Comment: It means exactly what it says, and is as far as I can tell consistent with the common use of the term "continuous random variable". Do you have more than one possible interpretation of the definition in mind?

Comment: Does it really say "for all single points $x\in X$"? That makes no sense - should be "for all $x\in\Bbb R$". Given that, it's hard to see how there's anything to "interpret"...

Comment: How is the update addressing @Mees' query?

Comment: @Did I am totally new to this field, so I just want to understand the sentence. I have read the basic concepts on Wikepedia but cannot weave them, like continuous, $P(X=x)=0$, random, together.

Comment: This may be so but what is unclear to you in them is most unclear (and actually you say nothing about it).

Comment: @Did I will update as Mees urged after more reading.

Comment: Roughly speaking, a continuous random variable is a random variable that can take on a continuous range of values, such as any value in an interval $[a,b]$ for example. For example, throw a dart at a dart board, and let $X$ be the distance from where the dart landed to the bullseye. You can see it's utterly unlikely that $X$ would be *exactly* equal to, say, $1.7$. So $P(X = 1.7) = 0$. The same goes for any other specific number. In contrast, for a discrete random variable there are only a finite (or countable) number of possible values, each with positive probability.

Comment: And that is why a continuous random variable is NOT characterized by a probability mass function, but rather by a probability density function, with the integral of that density function being a distribution function (or exceedance function) computed over a non-infinitesimal range of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that broadly, we can break random variables into **discrete** and **continuous** random variables.

**Discrete** random variables are ones that can only take on discrete values. Like rolling a die. You can get the values $1,2,3,4,5,6$. Or the number of people at a party. You can only have positive integer number of people. You can have $1,2,3,...$ people at the party. Or the amount of money you can win on a slot machine. The least amount you can win is say, $.01$.

**Continuous** random variables are ones where you can have any value in an interval. Say, someone's height. You can be exactly $5.0001294024902390...$ feet tall. Or the age when you die. You can be $80.2323999...$ years old. The idea is that any individual outcome is "extremely unlikely". So rather than asking about what is the probability of being exactly $5.00...$ feet tall we can ask "what's the probability that you're between $5$ and $5.1$ feet tall?". In these cases, we say the probability of being exactly $5$ feet tall is $0$.